# VBScript errors with GetObject call

Tags: windows-7, vbscript, wmi

The goal is to retrieve the Dell service tags of all systems in a list (pseudo-systems given  below in place of real system names)

The following script was originally used, and works just fine.

```
On Error Resume Next
strComputer=InputBox ("Enter the computer name of the server you'd like to query for Service Tag")
Set objWMIservice = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
WScript.Echo "Error: " & Err.number
Set colitems = objWMIservice.ExecQuery("Select SerialNumber from Win32_BIOS", , 48)
For Each objitem In colitems
WScript.Echo "Dell Service Tag: " & objitem.SerialNumber
Next
```

It asks for the user to input the system name, and then retrieves the tag.
However, there are 200+ systems to run, and it'd be nice to avoid having to type them all in manually.

My attempt to do just that (below) is close to right, but fails with error 70 codes on systems that the first script finds just fine.

```
On Error Resume Next

Dim systems, splitSystems, objWMIservice, fso, output, tag, mystr

systems = "sys1,sys2,sys3,sys4"
splitSystems = Split(systems,",")

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set output = fso.CreateTextFile("system_tags.csv", True)
output.WriteLine """System Name"",""Service Tag"""

For Each sys In splitSystems
    If Ping(sys) = True Then

        'Doesn't work
        mystr = "winmgmts:\\" & sys & "\root\cimv2"
        Set objWMIservice = GetObject(mystr)

        'Also doesn't work
        'Set objWMIservice = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & sys & "\root\cimv2")

        'Works just dandy
        'Set objWMIservice = GetObject("winmgmts:\\sys1\root\cimv2")

        If Err.number <> 0 Then
            'output.WriteLine """" & sys & """,""ERROR """ & Err.number
            WScript.Echo "Set objWMIservice = GetObject('" & mystr & "') failed from Err.code:" & Err.description
        Else
            For Each objitem In objWMIservice.ExecQuery("Select SerialNumber from Win32_BIOS",,48)
                tag = objitem.SerialNumber
            Next
            output.WriteLine """" & sys & """,""" & tag & """"
        End If
    Else
        output.WriteLine """" & sys & """,""OFFLINE"""
    End If
Next

MsgBox "All done!"

Function Ping(strComputer)
    Dim objShell, boolCode
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    boolCode = objShell.Run("Ping -n 1 -w 300 " & strComputer, 0, True)
    If boolCode = 0 Then
        Ping = True
    Else
        Ping = False
    End If
End Function
```

Can someone explain to me why the first two methods (commented "Doesn't work" and "Also doesn't work") fail, but hardcoding the system name works just fine?

EDIT: The lines in the latter script following the condition `If Err.number <> 0 Then` were updated to provide the error description. Output is as follows, with system names replaced with pseudonyms:

```
Set objWMIservice = GetObject('winmgmts:\\sys1\root\cimv2') failed from Err.code:Permission denied
Set objWMIservice = GetObject('winmgmts:\\sys3\root\cimv2') failed from Err.code:Permission denied
```

EDIT2: Further testing shows that it at least one issue is related to successfully finding the service tag of one system, and failing on the following system, which for some reason results in the previous `tag` being used

Comment: Have you considered that it may be a limitation of the operating system? I don't know if this would help any, but check some of these conditional settings for OS specific connection strings. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Definitely something to consider!  
All systems being checked are either Windows 7+ or Windows Server 2008+, and should all be configured to allow WMI connections.  
That being said, my big concern is why checking them individually works, but checking them in a loop doesn't. I can't see any reason why checking them in a loop should change anything about the initiated connection.

Comment: There are literally dozens of code examples online just like yours. Your code is solid, there's either something wrong with your input string with the systems in it, or the systems themselves. Some heavy logging on the exact commands should be helpful. For instance, if err.number <> 0 then output.writeline "Set objWMIservice = GetObject('winmgmts:\\" & sys & "\root\cimv2')" failed from err.code:" & err.description

Comment: That's what I was thinking, although I've no idea why both hardcoding it and receiving input from an input box (first script) work, but pulling from a array that's split from a hardcoded string doesn't.
Either way, I updated what you mentioned and put the results at the end. :)

Comment: Don't know if it's related, but the output you posted has a missing backslash in the diagnostics output: winmgmts:\ should read winmgmts:\\

Comment: If you get **Permission denied** it means the script is executed from a user account that does not have administrator level on the target system. Try run it with an account that is member of Domain Administrators.

Comment: @NathanRice I double checked and it's an error on my part. The string definitely reads winmgmts:\\.

Comment: @PatricK Although that seems like the simple answer, it doesn't explain why the first script works. Both are run with the same permissions on the same machine, which **is** a member of Domain Administrators.